# .htaccess mod_rewrite

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello i am trying to make it so that when you visit my site you don't have to put .php at the end this is what i am using but it isn't working (godaddy hosting)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

i just added the "`Options +FollowSymlinks`" today and it still didn't work.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled and working? Did you try other rules?

Comment: i am new to this how do i enable mod_rewrite

Comment: @Matthew Carter: Try a very simple rule like `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/?`.

Comment: i have custom error pages if that might affect anything

Comment: @Matthew Carter: Is there a directory with the same name so that the first condition might not be fulfilled?

Comment: no, does it have any thing to do with the hosting

Comment: @Matthew Carter: No, I guess not. You might want to play with mod_rewrite’s logging feature (see [`RewriteLogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel)) to see the internal processing of the requests.

Comment: fantastic i just changed the first line to Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

Comment: fantastic i just changed the first line to Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know yet what the "FollowSymLinks" does but the rest does that:

```
RewriteEngine On            <-- activates mod rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  <-- condition that says: request filename is not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f  <-- condition that says: request filename with the appendix .php is a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php  <-- take anything you get and put a .php behind it
```

to tell it in human words:
if the requested filename is not a directory and if you append .php to that filename and it is an existing file then do the rewrite rule which appends .php to the requested file

this works on my XAMPP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On            
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

is unnecessary. What shall that be for?

Comment: This will avoid infinite recursion as only requests get rewritten that can positively mapped onto an existing `.php` file.

Comment: in no way it is unnecessary! it prevents something like test.html of being rewritten to test.html.php!!